# Interpreting impulse value "c kg"

Tags: special-relativity, speed-of-light, momentum, units, unit-conversion

I have a small question about a physics exercise concerning the relativistic relationship between energy and momentum. The exercise says:

> We have 2 objects with rest mass 8 kg. We shoot the objects in opposite directions; both objects obtain an impuls of 6c kg. [...]

Here I'm a little bit confused on the meaning 6c kg, because I can't think of another way to read this than 6c per 1 kg, or 3c per 2 kg, 12c per 0.5 kg. That can't be right, first of all because this is not a fraction, and if I solve for $v$, I get $\frac{3c}{9+16c^2}$. So how can I interpret 6c kg?

Comment: I'm am not sure what there is to interpret - the value of the momentum of both objects is $6\cdot c \cdot 1\mathrm{ kg}$. What sort of interpretation do you need and why?

Comment: @ACuriousMind Well, for instance, what does this value mean if we're considering an object of 1 kg. It looks like we would have a velocity of 6c then, but that can't be right? Ohhh wait, I think I understand my mistake. If we are considering on object with mass 1 kg, then that means we have a $v\gamma$ of 6c, but then we would still need to solve for $v$! I forgot the relativistic relation, and used the classical one.

Comment: Yes, I would interpret this as meaning that $\gamma m v = 6c$.

Comment: Here is a place where paying close attention to the typographic conventions would give you certainty. The value is presumably $6c\,\mathrm{kg}$. Notice that 'kg' is typeset upright; that's a unit. But 'c' is typeset in italics; that's a variable or constant. impulse and momentum units are velocity times mass, so $c$ is a constant with units of velocity ... the speed of light.

Comment: @dmckee Oh right, because we're working with natural units we get kg as the unit for linear momentum! Thanks for pointing out the convention - that's very useful!

Comment: Sha, for future reference quick questions like this are often best asked [in the chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71/the-h-barbecue). That allows greater freedom for discussion than the main site does.